# Dynamic xpath in Selenium

Tags: selenium, xpath

How do I write an xpath expression for these kind of ids where the identifier contains numbers (ex: 11784) that change every build.

```
id='tab-11784-Customer'
id='tab-11784-Tracker'
```

Answer (score 1):

Question; why do you have to use Xpath in this scenario? Based on the fact you are searching for id, then css makes more sense

```
[id^=tab-][id$=-Customer]
```

If you must use Xpath then;

```
//*[starts-with(@id, 'tab-') and contains(@id, 'Customer')]
```

Comment: I am new to Selenium & i always thought Xpath as the final weapon to deal with this kind of challenges.

Comment: What challenge are you facing?